# Data structure: Link a table to one of several other

Tags: sql, database

I have a database table `SavedData` which contains a field `type_data`. I need to link that table to one of the tables `SpecificData1`, `SpecificData2` and `SpecificData3`, depending on what is in the `type_data` field.

I have thought of a few solutions, but none of them looks great... :

1. <strike>Have 3 fields in `SavedData` called `specificdata1_id`,  `specificdata2_id` and  `specificdata3_id`, and one of them is set, with the 2 others `NULL`. I can then use the specific data for which the id is not null.</strike> After some reading, I've seen this one is really bad, which is understandable.
2. Have 1 field in `SavedData` called `specificdata_id`, and depending on the `type_data` I know in which table I need to look for that id.
3. Put all the fields from the 3 specific data tables in the `SavedData` table and use only the data that I need depending on the value of `type_data`.

What would be the best solution ? Is there another one that could solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a seperate table to just save 2 columns. `Type_data, specificdata_id` Use this table to just save the relationship between your `SavedData and Specificdat1/2/3`